# How to take input java util date and display it @ frontend as sql date in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-framework-beans

I'm trying to take i/p date from user as Java util  date. However When I'm trying to display it on the browser using jsp page, it is showing util date .. how can i convert it to sql date and display it..

#### Model Class

```
import java.util.Date;
//import java.time.LocalDate;



import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;


public class Details {
    @NotEmpty(message=" Username is not entered")
    private String name;
    //private String lang;
    private String module;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")  //yyyy-mm-dd
    @NotNull(message=" Start date is mandatory")
    private Date startdate;

    public Date getStartdate() {
        return startdate;
    }
    public void setStartdate(Date startdate) {
        this.startdate = startdate;
    }}
```

#### Controller Class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class DetailsController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String viewPage(Model model) {

        Details detail = new Details();
        model.addAttribute("detail", detail);
        
        return "details";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("detail") Details detail, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "details";
        }
        else
            {return "detailsSummary";}
                }

}
```

#### details.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error{color:red}
</style>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="submit" method="post" modelAttribute="detail">
    
        Username:<form:input path="name"/><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
        <br><br>
        Startdate:<form:input path="startdate" type="date"/><form:errors path="startdate" cssClass="error"/><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### detailssummary.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Summary page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Details submitted!</h3>

    <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>${detail.name}</td>
        </tr> 
        
                <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>${detail.startdate}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

```
-----------------------------------
```

I also need to run sql queries using that date. Kindly help me out. Also say, if I want to take input an end date but I have to do the validation that it should be more than start date., the how to do it. Please help me out with these two things.

Comment: @OleV.V.  Please don't give this type of general answers. I want the code such That I can display the date on the screen which is taken as input.. If possible kindly provide me the same.

Comment: (I have deleted my comments since you didn’t want them.)